# CSS plus(+) selector in Wordpress

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a dropcap in my Wordpress site, to the first letter of the first paragraph following the H1.  I'm using a selector as follows:

```
h1 + p:first-letter {
font-family:Almendra;
font-size:300%;
etc...
}
```

Nothing is being selected.  If I remove the h1 +, every paragraph's first letter is selected.

My page is here: http://www.thelionscall.com/2012/10/19/forum-testing/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `+` is for *adjacent sibblings*.  The `h1` and `p` are not sibblings, the `h1` and the `div` (`p`'s parent) are sibblings.

Answer (score 1):

The elements are too far apart. Need to either put them in the same parent, or use their containers... this might get you closer:

```
header h1 + div.entry-meta p:first-letter {
    font-size: 300%;
    /* etc... */
}
```